# How to execute dynamic procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to make a dynamic procedure which populates a table within data already exist in the table. I have two variables for primary column and not primary key columns. I passed a sequence (generate.nextval) to primary key column. It will insert specific number of rows which is passed as a parameter (amount)

```
Create or replace procedure v_populate (table_name in varchar2, amount in number)
IS
v_pk varchar2(1000);
v_pk2 varchar2(1000);
V_dyntask LONG;
V_dyntask2 LONG;

CURSOR C1 IS 
'select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(xmlagg(xmlforest(cols.column_name ) 
ORDER BY cols.column_name ),''</COLUMN_NAME><COLUMN_NAME>'','',''),''<COLUMN_NAME>''),''</COLUMN_NAME>'') XMLAGG  --cols.column_name 
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name ='''||table_name||'''AND cons.constraint_type NOT IN (''P'',''U'',''R'')
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position';

CURSOR C2 IS
'select 
                    REPLACE( 
                      REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(xmlagg(xmlforest(cols.column_name ) ORDER BY cols.column_name )
                               ,''</COLUMN_NAME><COLUMN_NAME>'','','')
                              ,''<COLUMN_NAME>'')
                             ,''</COLUMN_NAME>'') XMLAGG --cols.column_name 
               FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
              WHERE cols.table_name ='''||table_name||'''
                AND cons.constraint_type = ''P''
                AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
                AND cons.owner = cols.owner
           ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position
              ';

BEGIN

FOR F1 in C1 
LOOP
v_pk:=C1.COLUMN_NAME;
END LOOP;

FOR F2 in C2 
LOOP
v_pk2:=C2.COLUMN_NAME;
END LOOP;

V_dyntask2:= 'INSERT INTO ' ||table_name|| ' 
                        ( '||v_pk2||' , '||v_pk||' ) 
                 select generate.nextval,'||v_pk||' 
                   from ' ||table_name || '
                  where rownum <='||amount;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_dyntask2;
COMMIT;
end;
```

I keep getting this error:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(xmlagg(xmlforest(cols.column_name" when expecting one of the following:     ( select  The symbol "select" was substituted for "select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(xmlagg(xmlforest(cols.column_name" to continue. 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     , * & - + / at mod remainder rem       as    from ||

Comment: I'm not going to debug it for you. A piece of advice, though: instead of executing it, first `dbms_output.put_line(v_dyntask2)` and check whether it looks OK. Of course it doesn't - otherwise, it would work. Don't execute it until you fix the error.

Comment: I tried it now, it gives the same error. I am a bit new to plsql probably I am missing something @Littlefoot

Comment: New to PL/SQL? Couldn't you find something simpler than dynamic SQL? Well, you'll have to start over, creating v_dyntask2 step-by-step, testing **frequently**.

Comment: Your code looks really strange, what do you try to achieve? The loops are useless, you just take the last row form the query. In your query your first create  XML object with `xmlagg(xmlforest(...` but then you remove the XML tags again to get plain text.

Comment: Data type `LONG` is deprecated for almost 20 years, don't use it.

Comment: I was trying to get column names written side by side. I have oracle 10g so it doesn't support LISTAGG. I wasn't that sure either about if I should use for loops. I was just trying to pass column names to variable. @Wernfried Domscheit

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need a dynamic query for cursors.

Use the following code and let me know if it works:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE V_POPULATE (
    P_TABLE_NAME   IN           VARCHAR2,
    AMOUNT       IN           NUMBER
)
IS
    V_PK VARCHAR2(1000);
    V_PK2 VARCHAR2(1000);
    V_DYNTASK LONG;
    V_DYNTASK2 LONG;

BEGIN

FOR F1 in (select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(xmlagg(xmlforest(cols.column_name ) 
ORDER BY cols.column_name ),'</COLUMN_NAME><COLUMN_NAME>',','),'<COLUMN_NAME>'),'</COLUMN_NAME>') column_name  --cols.column_name 
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = P_TABLE_NAME  
AND cons.constraint_type NOT IN ('P','U','R')
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position) 
LOOP
v_pk:=F1.COLUMN_NAME;
END LOOP;

FOR F2 in (select 
        REPLACE( 
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(xmlagg(xmlforest(cols.column_name ) ORDER BY cols.column_name )
                   ,'</COLUMN_NAME><COLUMN_NAME>',',')
                  ,'<COLUMN_NAME>')
                 ,'</COLUMN_NAME>') column_name --cols.column_name 
   FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
  WHERE cols.table_name =P_table_name
    AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
    AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
    AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position) 
LOOP
v_pk2:=F2.COLUMN_NAME;
END LOOP; 

V_dyntask2:= 'INSERT INTO ' || P_table_name|| ' 
                        ( '||v_pk2||' , '||v_pk||' ) 
                 select generate.nextval,'||v_pk||' 
                   from ' ||P_table_name || '
                  where rownum <='||amount;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_dyntask2;
COMMIT;
end;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tejash. But now it gives this error: PLS-00302: component 'COLUMN_NAME' must be declared

Comment: In cursor, There was no column_name alias so it was giving the error. Updated the answer. Check now!!

Comment: Thanks @ Tejash !!! Now I can run the script without an error. I know I am asking too much but when I execute the procedure I get an error stating: PLS-00357:Table,View Or Sequence reference 'EMPLOYEES' not allowed in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic string for cursor and you don't need to juggle with XML. I would do it like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE v_populate (table_name IN VARCHAR2, amount IN NUMBER)

    v_pk VARCHAR2(1000);
    v_pk2 VARCHAR2(1000);
    sqlstr VARCHAR2(30000);

    CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT cols.column_name
    FROM all_constraints cons
        JOIN all_cons_columns cols USING (OWNER, constraint_name)
    WHERE cols.table_name = table_name
        AND cons.constraint_type NOT IN ('P','U','R');
    ORDER BY cols.column_name; -- For check constraints ('C') POSITION is NULL, thus 'ORDER BY POSITION' is pointless!

    CURSOR C2 IS
    SELECT cols.column_name, cols.position
    FROM all_constraints cons
        JOIN all_cons_columns cols USING (OWNER, constraint_name)
    WHERE cols.table_name = table_name
        AND cons.constraint_type = 'P';

BEGIN

    sqlstr := 'INSERT INTO ' ||table_name|| ' ( ';
    FOR aCol IN C2 LOOP
        sqlstr := sqlstr || aCol.COLUMN_NAME||',';
    END LOOP;

    FOR aCol IN C1 LOOP
        sqlstr := sqlstr || aCol.COLUMN_NAME||',';
    END LOOP;
    sqlstr := REGEXP_REPLACE(sqlstr, ',$', ') ');

    sqlstr := sqlstr || 'SELECT generate.nextval,';
    FOR aCol IN C1 LOOP
        sqlstr := sqlstr || aCol.COLUMN_NAME||',';
    END LOOP;
    sqlstr := REGEXP_REPLACE(sqlstr, ',$', ' ');
    sqlstr := sqlstr || 'FROM ' ||table_name|| ' WHERE ROWNUM <= :a';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( sqlstr ); -- Only for testing to verify the generated command

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr USING amount;

END;
```

Be aware, the procedure will fail if your table has a composite Primary Key , i.e. Primary Key build by more then one column. It also fails if your table does not have a Primary Key at all.

Maybe you should skip the Primary Key and apply `generate.nextval` via Row-Level BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Note, also 17 years old Oracle 10g was already supporting modern ANSI join syntax.